# "flyway.locations:" if sql files are in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, flyway, dbmigrate

I am asked to perform DB migration. My script files are in S3 bucket. I am migrating using flyway. How can i mention `flyway.locations:` for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This is an outstanding feature request for Flyway. Please upvote it at https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1961 and we will consider for 6.3!